# When do tensor products of C*-algebras commute with colimits?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, reference-request

Let $I$ be a filtered poset, which you should think of as being huge. Let $A_i$ be an $I$-diagram of $C^{\star}$-algebras and let $A$ be the colimit of this diagram; if necessary, we can also assume that all structure maps $A_i \rightarrow A_j$ are inclusions. Given a nuclear $C^{\star}$-algebra $N$, is it then true that tensoring with $N$ commutes with the colimit, i.e. that $A \otimes N$ is the colimit of $A_i \otimes N$? In particular, I am interested in the case $N = C(X)$ for some compact space $X$.

I expect this to be true (and seem to have a proof for C(X) at least), but have not been able to find anything in the literature, so a reference would be welcome.

Comment: In the category of von Neumann algebras, the functor $- \otimes N$ preserves coequalizers [Guichardet, Bull Sci Math 90:41-64, 1966, Prop 8.3]. I would hope the same holds for C*-algebras, so that it would suffice to concentrate on coproducts. But also, in the category of von Neumann algebras, colimits do not preserve flatness [Guichardet, Remark 8.2], which is a bad sign.

Comment: By the way, preserving filtered colimits is the same as preserving colimits of chains [Adamek&Rosicky, Cambridge Univ Press, 1994, Cors 1.5 & 1.7]. So you may assume that I is a total order. If all the maps $A_i \to A_j$ are inclusions, doesn't that make the colimit just the closure of the union of all the $A_i$, leading to a trivial proof? 

Comment: You definitely want $N$ to be an exact $C^*$-algebra, not just a nuclear one, for something like that to be true.

Comment: Chris, what tensor product are you/Guichardet using? I seem to recall that Guichardet defines a tensor which gives decent SMC properties but isn't the spatial t.p. And at C*-level the whole issue of tensor products is **MUCH** more complicated

Comment: @Ulrich Pennig: all nuclear C*-algebras are exact...

Comment: My **guess** (but I don't have time to check the details right now, hence this is merely a comment) is that the *maximal* tensor product of C*-algebras should behave nicely, or at least better, with colimits. Then when $N$ is nuclear the max and min tensor products coincide, so $N \otimes$ would behave nicely.

Comment: For algebras like $C(X)$ (resp. $C^ast(X))$ a colimit correspond to a limit of realcompact (resp. compact) spaces (this colimits can do in in Topological spaces category, because are full reflexive subcategories, then the inclusion create limits). THen if we have a representation theorem "each $C^ast$ algebra (of a some specific type) is isomorphic to some funtion spaces $C_X$ on some topological space $X$" and there exist a  isomorphism  $C_X\otimes C_Y\cong C(X\times Y)$ the question become topological. (also for disprove it)    

Comment: error above: $C^ast:=C^{\ast}$

Comment: Sergio,the question is about the category of all C*-algebras, not just the abelian ones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $N$ is exact and the tensor products are minimal then $A\otimes N$ is the colimit of the $A_i\otimes N$'s. Say the connecting maps are $\phi_{i,j}$. Then to check that $A\otimes N$
is the colimit of $\{A_i\otimes N,\phi_{i,j}\otimes\mathrm{id}_N\}$ two properties must be verified:

(1) the union of the ranges of the maps $\phi_{i,\infty}\otimes \mathrm{id}_N$ is dense in $A\otimes N$,

(2) for each $i$, $\ker (\phi_{i,\infty}\otimes \mathrm{id}_N)=\overline{\bigcup_{j>i} \ker({\phi_{i,j}\otimes \mathrm{id}_N})}$.

The first property is straightforward, since the span of the elementary tensors $\phi_{i,\infty}(a)\otimes n$ is dense. The second property follows from the fact that $\ker(\phi_{i,\infty}\otimes \mathrm{id}_N)=\ker(\phi_{i,\infty})\otimes N$ and the correspoding property (2) for the colimit of the $A_i$'s.

That $\ker(\phi\otimes \mathrm{id}_N)=\ker(\phi)\otimes N$ follows, if $\phi$ is surjective, by exactness of $N$, if $\phi$ is injective, by the minimality of $\otimes$
(the minimal tensor product behaves well with respect to inclusions), and the general case is a composite of those two.